# How to remove a scope of a component injected from a parent directive

Tags: angularjs, dom

I have a directive that dynamically adds child custom directives to the DOM based on some input. Everything works fine. But when the input changes and I re-render the DOM with a different set of child custom directives, the old scopes of the child custom directives are not deleted and hence, the event handlers attached to them are still in memory.

I am re-rendering the DOM by just setting element[0].innerHTML = ''.
Is there a way to delete/destroy the scopes of the custom directive? I saw in some articles that scope.$destroy can be called but how to get a reference of the scope of the child custom directive?

```
const linker = function (scope, element) {
scope.$watch('data', function () {
    reRenderToolbar();
}, true);

const reRenderToolbar = function () {
    element[0].innerHTML = '';
    _.forEach(scope.data, function (item, key) {
        const directive = item.CustomDirective;
        scope.options = item.options || {};
        html = '<' + directive + ' options="options"></' + directive + '>';
        element.append(html);
    }


   });
}

    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    };
```

Comment: Directive such as `ng-repeat`, `ng-include`, `ng-if`, .etc, which create and destroy DOM, create a new child scope before compiling contents. They link the compiled contents to the new scope. When they remove the element, they destroy the associated child scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was not destroying the childscope in the parent as my app is multiscoped. This article helped me http://www.mattzeunert.com/2014/11/03/manually-removing-angular-directives.html
Code:

```
    const linker = function (scope, element) {
scope.$watch('data', function () {
    reRenderToolbar();
}, true);
let childScope;

const reRenderToolbar = function () {
if(childScope) {
childScope.$destroy();
}
    element[0].innerHTML = '';
    _.forEach(scope.data, function (item, key) {
        const directive = item.CustomDirective;
        scope.options = item.options || {};
        html = '<' + directive + ' options="options"></' + directive + '>';
        element.append(html);
    }

   });
}


    childScope = scope.$new()
    $compile(element.contents())(childScope);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

on your custom directive handle the destroy event

```
directive("CustomDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',              
        template: '<div >Custom Directive</div>',                
        link: function(scope, element){                  
            scope.$on("$destroy",function() {
                element.remove();
            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I have tried those already. even the following doesnt work `link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$on("$destroy", () => {

                alert("Destroyed element on listening to scope");
                element.remove();
            });
            element.on('$destroy', () => {
                alert("Destroyed scope on listening to element");
                scope.$destroy();
            });
        }`

Comment: I cannot have `restict:C` as mine is an element